# Copy few documents in a collection to another collection in mongo DB

Tags: database, mongodb, collections

I have two collections , one where all documents are stored and the other where the documents will be stored after processing. 
I am new with mongo and would like to know if there is any method to copy the documents from one collection to the other ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
db.firstColllection.aggregate([
    {$limit: 10},
    {$out: "secondCollection"}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy all files, we can use db.source.copyTo("target") as well