# Copy documents from one collection to another in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, collections

I have a problem but it seems to me that all the solutions I've seen are solving a problem more complex than mine.

I'm relatively new to MongoDB, but I've been using it with Apache Nutch to store crawled documents. As I am crawling in stages, and assessing each crawled result differently, to get the stats, I have been storing the results in different collections.

All I want to do is put these collections together into one big collection so I can translate and classify. All the fields are the SAME, so I don't need to add any new field.

This is the insert query I have been using for each collection:

```
new_crawl_130422_data.insert_one(
                        {
                        "database_url": proj_database_url,
                        "database_project_id": proj_database_id,
                        "projectname": proj_database_name,
                        "version": version,
                        "boost": boost,
                        "content": content,
                        "digest": digest,
                        "title": title,
                        "timestamp": timestamp,
                        "url": website,
                        "language": language

                        }
```

So, collection 1, and collection 2, have these same fields. Obviously, there would be multiple documents in each collection that have the same `database_project_id` as these are records mapped based on urls that match, and they have been transferred from Solr. Where the project name and url match, the document has been assigned the project_id, to show that it contains data for that project.

I thought it would be possible to just add on one collection to the end of the other like a list, but I have looked at these solutions - [Copy few documents in a collection to another collection in mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133797/copy-few-documents-in-a-collection-to-another-collection-in-mongo-db) , [Insert all documents from one collection into another collection in MongoDB database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272955/insert-all-documents-from-one-collection-into-another-collection-in-mongodb-data) , [Spring data mongodb- copy a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23611576/spring-data-mongodb-copy-a-collection) and they all seem to be doing more complicated things than I need.

I don't want to change any collection, just create one large collection by putting two or more collections together.

I also saw this - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/, but it is deprecated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To combine collections into 1, we can use [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) another way to do it is with [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/), and [$out](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to create the new combined collection. Not sure what you need to do, but maybe check them.

Comment: @Takis thanks. Will try this with Wernfried's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you like to copy all data then simply run:

```
db.new_crawl_130422_data.aggregate([
    {$out: "secondCollection"}
])
```

Note, all existing data in `secondCollection` will be deleted. If you like to add, i.e. merge the documents and keep existing data, then use:

```
db.new_crawl_130422_data.aggregate([
    {$merge: "secondCollection"}
])
```

If you have a large data set, then see [How to copy a collection from one database to another in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-to-copy-a-collection-from-one-database-to-another-in-mongodb/67077465#67077465)

Comment: thank you for this. How can this be amended to merge the two collections, say collection1 and collection2 into a third collection - collection3? This would mean that collection1 and collection2 would still be available, and collection3 will be a combination of both collections.

Comment: Run two commands: `db.collection1.aggregate([{$merge: "collection3"}])` and `db.collection2.aggregate([{$merge: "collection3"}])` Would be the simplest. Or use [$unionWith](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/)